# Why do we compare the return value of InputStream read() method with -1?

Tags: java

In this while statement `while ((c = in.read()) != -1)`  what does -1 mean? See the below program for more details :

```
 import java.*;

    public class CopyFile 
    {

     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
         {  

          FileInputStream in = null;

          FileOutputStream out = null;

          try {
             in = new FileInputStream("input.txt ");
             out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

             int c;
             while ((c = in.read()) != -1) 
            {
                out.write(c);
             }
          }
         finally 
        {
             if (in != null) {
                in.close();
             }
             if (out != null) {
                out.close();
             }
          }
       }
```

}

Comment: it represents end of file. btw what's so hard about reading the docs for this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple reading of the docs for the method is self explanatory

Answer (score 2):

The [read() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) returns `int`

> Returns:
>
> the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

Just to know if the data is still there or it reached end of the file.